# Varnish and conditional codes in php

Tags: php, wordpress, varnish

I have a code like this in PHP

```
//get referer   
$reffere_Url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
//if referer is abc.com then show the referer slider at home.
if (strpos($reffere_Url, 'abc') !== false && $home_referal_slider!="") 
{ 
    $home_slider = $home_referal_slider; 
}
else
{ 
   $home_slider =  $home_slider; 
}
```

but it always returning $home_slider even if condition gets true.
This is because of varnish installed and its serving cached version of the webpage. Please help how can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Varnish what and how to cache.

First option is to override the `vcl_hash` in Varnish to include the referer:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.referer);
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (lookup);
}
```

But this will probably impact you cache ratio very badly - every different referer will get their unique cache pool.

Much neater way is to use `Vary` headers from the backend - this again lets Varnish know that this response cache depends on the referer header. I use mostly `Vary` headers so I can control from the backend how Varnish behaves.

In vanilla PHP:
`header('Vary', 'Referer');`
But note that this needs to be set regardless of which `$home_slider` you serve. So this again will impact your cache ratio badly if you have the logic on every page.

One more option would be to use Edge Side Includes (ESI) to just get the slider from the backend so that the rest of the page can be cached normally, but this is much more complicated.

So probably the best solution would be to pass all the traffic with referer abc.com to the backend. Hoping this is not the majority of your visitors it has the least impact on your cache ratio.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.referer ~ "abc\.com") {
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

(Examples based on Varnish 4)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to check req.http.Referer value in vcl_rec to return(pass) but it did not worked.

There is an another solution of this just add a query string (?ex=exTrDz) to the url onto the referer page. This will do the trick.